# Slider Maximum value from other class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

//class 1

```
int sliderMaximum;
float sliderMaximumDigital;


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
class 2 *V1 = [[class 2 alloc] init];


sliderMaximum = V1.TeamAmountAfterSave;
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sliderMaximum];
sliderMaximumDigital = [yourNumber floatValue];

[sliderTeamSelect setMaximumValue:sliderMaximumDigital];

}
```

//class 2

```
int teamAmount;

@synthesize TeamAmountAfterSave; (In .h file (@property int TeamAmountAfterSave;))

TeamAmountAfterSave = teamAmount;
```

// This code almost works correctly the only problem is my sliders Maximum Value is set to 0.

// ps. teamAmount has the value of how many times a button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're allocating a new view controller (`[[CompetitionViewController alloc] init]`) and then you're immediately querying one of its properties (`sliderMaximum = V1.TeamAmountAfterSave`). So unless the `init` of `CompetitionViewController` doesn't explicitly set the value read by the property `TeamAmountAfterSave`, it will of course be 0.

I've got no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you want a manager object (possibly a singleton) that stores/manages your data. A view controller is not the place to do it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion what I could use to store the value of teamAmount? So it will stay even when I close the app? I have try'd using NSUserdefaults to safe it in but I can not extract an int out of that.

Comment: Never mind I solved it already seems i was suing a different NSUserDefaults.